# ocpsoft.org PrettyTime: Could not find any registered converter-class

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, myfaces, prettyfaces, apache-tomee

I found this fairly incredible date conversion library for JSF called Pretty Time. I've included the maven coordinates into my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettytime-integration-jsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the relavent part of my page:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Last Updated</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.lastUpdated}">
        <f:converter converterId="org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter" />
    </h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

I'm deploying out to TomEE v1.5.1+. I get this exception. Am I missing a step? I did notice that the class `org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter` isn't marked with a `@FacesConverter` annotation. Could this be a problem?

```
Mar 25, 2013 2:31:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
javax.faces.FacesException: Could not find any registered converter-class by converterId : prettyTimeConverter
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:164)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:45)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:66)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:237)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl$TemplateManagerImpl.apply(TemplateContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl.includeDefinition(TemplateContextImpl.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:460)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:94)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:294)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:156)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:394)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:448)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:426)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:244)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:179)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:452)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at fm.thehub.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

EDIT:
I'm leaning towards a TomEE/MyFaces bug... or feature. Whatever you want to call it:

The faces-config for my project uses the 2.1 namespace:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
```

Whereas the prettytime one uses the deprecated one:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
   version="1.2">
```

Adding the converter to my project's faces config makes everything work just peachy.

Comment: Have you included the prettytime dependency itself? Look at [step 1](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/). JSF isn't finding your converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The converter is defined in a bundled faces-config.XML - https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime/blob/master/jsf/src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml

I would make sure that you have all dependencies required. The core jar and the jsf integration both.

You may have found some kind of bug in tomee, but I find that extremely unlikely. I'll try to take a closer look in a few hours.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a TomEE or myfaces bug as well... My workaround is to add it to my project's faces-config for right now

Comment: Fairly certain it's a myfaces or tomee bug. I'll take this answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

You JSF implementation complains that it cannot find a converter with id `prettyTimeConverter`. But in the code you posted you are referencing `org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter` (which is correct). You should double check the converter ID a try again. I guess it's just a typo.

Comment: `<converter-id>org.ocpsoft.PrettyTimeConverter</converter-id>` is listed in the faces-config file of the pretty time jar. Is there a reason that shouldn't be used?

Comment: No, that's what you should use, but it seems like the error message showed a different converterId than that, which is what christian was pointing out.